# Read CSV file in Python and then append to existing Key

Tags: python, csv

I am currently trying to write a little programm to keep track of books. That programm is working fine so far, it stores the name of an author as a key, and the booktitle as the value to an empty dictionary. If the key already exists, it appends the value to the existing key. What I would like to do now is to read the rows from the csv file when the programm is started again, so that the programm knows what keys already exist and can append to it again if necessary.

I hope I could make it clear what I am trying to do.The programm is just for learning purposes, so if you could just point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

```
import csv

bücher = {}
def buch_daten():
    while True:
        autor = input("Bitte Namen des Autors eingeben! ")
        titel = input("Bitte den Titel des Buches eingeben! ")
        if autor in bücher:
            bücher[autor].append(titel)
        else:
            bücher[autor]=[titel]
        weiter = input("Noch etwas hinzufügen? (y/n)")
        if weiter == "y":
            continue
        elif weiter == "n":
            print("Danke für die Eingabe:")
            break
        else:
            print("Falsche Eingabe, dass Programm wird beendet.")
            break

def save_dict():
    with open('books2.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['autor', 'titel']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        for key, val in bücher.items():
            writer.writerow({"autor": key, "titel": val})
    print(f"Der Autor {key} und der Titel {val} wurden der Datei hinzugefügt.")



buch_daten()
save_dict()
print(bücher)
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your problem is, but a general loader would be

```
def load_dict():
    try:
        with open('books2.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
            for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
               bücher[row["autor"]] = row["titel"]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Notice the `FileNotFoundError` exception handling, so when the csv is not present it won't raise an error. Then you could add a call before the `buch_daten`

```
load_dict()
buch_daten()
save_dict()
```

`csv.DictReader` returns an iterable object with a dictionary structure, so every row would contain

```
{'autor': author_name, 'title': list_of_book_titles}
```

Also, you shouldn't append to an existing CSV file, but you must write in it instead:

```
def save_dict():
    with open('books2.csv', 'w+', newline='') as csvfile:
    […]
```

If you append onto a file you can only insert new rows, but that forbids you from editing authors that were already in the CSV itself. You could insert duplicate authors, but that would then defeat the point of the CSV structure.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you. Next time I am gonna try to explain a little bit better whats the problem I am having.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to save the dictionary for re-use, I'd suggesting using the `pickle` module to serialize it:

```
import pickle

pickle.dump(bücher, "/path/to/write/file.pickle")
```

You can then restore the dictionary with the `load` method to read the file:

```
bücher = pickle.load("/path/to/write/file.pickle")
```

Comment: keeping binary dumps around is having pain for nothing... python's dicts map almost 1 to 1 to json, which humanly readable and modifiable

Comment: I was also trying to save it as a json file, but then I still had the problem that I couldnt figure out how to read the file and then append to it again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
    if autor in bücher:
        bücher[autor].append(titel)
    else:
        bücher[autor]=[titel]
```

You can use setdefault (or use defaultdict)

```
bücher.setdefault(autor, []).append(titel)
```